# "He was employed since 2007"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, sentence-choice, past-vs-past-perfect

> "He was employed since 2007"(to date)".(is incorrect)

> "He was employed from 2007 to 2020".(is correct)

> "He had been employed since 2007".(is correct)

I believe that with "since", I should not use "was employed"(though sometimes people use) but the correct will be "had been employed". Am I interpreting it rightly?

Comment: Yes, it should be "He has been employed since 2007".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say, "He has been employed since 2007 (and still is)," or "He had been unemployed  since 2007 (at which point something happened," or even "He was employed after 2007," but not "He was employed since 2007."